# How can I avoid to get data again in the case 'select then update'

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008

Currently, my table (table A) has around 10.000.000 records. Every day, there are 100 records come. They are new and not been processed. So, Process column = 0. I'm using SQL Server 2008.

In my business, I need to do 2 steps:

1. Getting data are new (Process = 0), do something, and insert to table B.
2. Update Process = 1 at table A.

So, at step 1, I got them with WHERE clause to get these 100 records.
At step 2, I have to use WHERE clause one more time to get and update them.

I think, with getting data twice, the performance will not good, right?

Can someone advise me what should I do in this case so that I just need to query ONLY one time?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you having performance problems? How much time does each step takes?

Comment: Look at Merge statement and also increase your rate of acceptence

Answer (score 3):

Consider the OUTPUT clause:

```
UPDATE A
SET    Process = 1
OUTPUT INSERTED.column1,
       INSERTED.column2,
       …
INTO   B (column1, column2, …)
WHERE  Process = 0
;
```

Note that, [according to the manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx), the `B` table cannot:

> - Have enabled triggers defined on it.
> - Participate on either side of a FOREIGN KEY constraint.
> - Have CHECK constraints or enabled rules.

If anything of the above is true with regard to the table `B`, you could use a temporary table or a table variable as an intermediate storage before finally inserting data into `B`:

```
DECLARE @newdata TABLE (columns);
UPDATE A
SET    Process = 1
OUTPUT INSERTED.column1,
       INSERTED.column2,
       …
INTO   @newdata (column1, column2, …)
WHERE  Process = 0
;
INSERT INTO B (columns)
SELECT columns FROM @newdata
;
```

Comment: thank you but my table does not have enough those conditions.

Answer (score 2):

SQL server holds results from previous queries in cache. So if you have useful primary keys (say: small, clustered surrogate keys), the second query shouldn't be an issue.

If you want to create larger batches (e.g. 10000 items at once), you could use a temp table to store the primary keys your are handling in a batch. This way, you don't need to pass too many keys in a query.

Avoid premature optimization. Identify the performance problem first - if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use trigger for your problem:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_A ON  A
   AFTER INSERT
AS BEGIN
    INSERT INTO B (Column1, Column2, ...)
    SELECT I.Column1, I.Column2, ...
    FROM INSERTED I
    WHERE I.Process = 1
END
```